# Wrong caller ID showed for call and "000000" in calls journal

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, caller-id

My friend has an issue with her iPhone. For some reason, the phone app suddenly started to show the wrong caller name. After this she tried to logout/login into iCloud and then all callers in the call journal displayed as "00000000". In the Contacts app she can see the correct names with matching phone numbers. Sometimes, the call can have the name of one contact but photo of another one. Contacts are also sometimes shuffled for outgoing calls. Same problem with iMessage.

[image]

This is not a new phone, there have been no restores from backup recently, also there have been no new iOS devices connected to this Apple ID recently. She has been using the same phone company for a long time (Vodafone).

And these 00000000000 calls are not spam, it's a real people.

The phone was updated iOS 12.4.1 when she got this issue and it didn't help - she still had broken contacts.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: 00000000000 calls are usually SPAM/spoofed calls. If she answers calls from one of these numbers, what happens? Are they legitimate persons she knows, who are trying to reach her?

Comment: As far as I understand, it's a real people. And also we still have a problem with shuffling photos + names, and calling wrong person. Something completely wrong with contacts in that phone.

Comment: I suggest you back the iPhone up to iTunes and [reset it to factory settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252).

Comment: Tried it, surprisingly it didn't help.

Comment: Factory reset didn't help?  That sounds pretty strange.  Did you sign into iCloud after the factory reset or use it as a completely empty phone?  Because it sounds like your friend's address book is corrupt and causing this.  Logging into iCloud or bringing any type of backup back onto the phone would likely bring back the problem.

Comment: Sound reasonable, because, as I found out, that problem is also exists for Whatsapp chats. Said her to try, I'll post here about results.

Comment: What information is displayed when the info button (the "I" in a circle) is tapped?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following solution but you need to take care of it from Macbook which is using same Apple ID.

It is best to always have a backup before attempting something like this

- Open the AddressBook folder located on:

  ~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook
- In that folder, you will find three files:

  a.  addressbook-v22.abcddb

  b. addressbook-v22.abcddb-wal

  c. addressbook-v22.abcddb-shm

Delete them.

3. Open Contacts and your list of contacts should quickly populate as the index is rebuilt.